# Question about ILS approach categories

Tags: approach, ils, faa-approval

I was reading about FAAs ILS approach categories minimums and have a question!

Category II. DH 100 feet and RVR 1,200 feet (with autoland or HUD to touchdown and **noted on authorization**, RVR 1,000 feet);

To what authorization it refers? To an authorization placed in the remarks section of the instrument approach allowing a CAT II approach to have a RVR as low as 1000 feet if the pilot uses a HUD to touchdown for example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The note you are referring to

`RVR 10 authorized with specific OPSPEC, MSPEC, or LOA approval and use of autoland or HUD to touchdown`

The FAA must authorize the operator to use a lower RVR for CAT II approaches.  The FAA would review the training program and ensure adequate check pilots are approved to validate the training program and authorize the crew to use RVR 10.

See https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/section-61.67

Comment: Thank you! And in the instrument approach chart the minimums would have a RVR of 1000 FT along with a note stating that a minimum equipment and aircrew certification is required right?

Comment: @Breaach  The authorization would be in the company's OPSPEC (or their MSPEC, if they use that, or a specific Letter of Authorization from the FAA to that company). As I understand it, if you're authorized for Cat III, you can use your Cat III procedures with the Cat II chart & 1,000 RVR. Otherwise, the higher (probably 1,200 RVR) mins on the chart apply..

Comment: Usually the approach chart shows the minimums that are approved for everyone.  If they minimums are lower for some specific reason, there will be a note on the new minimums and the method to be authorized down to the new mins.